# How can I dynamically change FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS of Android status and navigation bars in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

I have a `FlyoutPage` which has a `NavigationPage` which is initialized with a `HomePage` (`ContentPage`) via `PushAsync`.

```
_navigation = new NavigationPage();
_navigation.PushAsync(new HomePage());
```

If a user opens a `SettingsPage` (`ContentPage`) it is also pushed to the navigation page:

```
_navigation.PushAsync(new SettingsPage());
```

and popped off when the user wants to return to the `HomePage`:

```
_navigation.PopAsync();
```

My problem is:

- `HomePage` background is drawn on the entire screen, including **behind** the status and navigation bars
- `SettingsPage` is drawn only **between** the status and navigation bars

and I am having problems toggling between the two states.

I am using the following dependency service method to do the toggle:

```
public class StatusBarStyleMgr_Android : IStatusBarStyleMgr
{
    public void SetSystemTheme(bool light, Xamarin.Forms.Color color)
    {
        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.M)
        {
            Android.Views.Window win = MainAct.Window;

            win.ClearFlags(WindowManagerFlags.TranslucentStatus);
            win.ClearFlags(WindowManagerFlags.TranslucentNavigation);
            win.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.DrawsSystemBarBackgrounds);

            //set text color
            win.InsetsController?.SetSystemBarsAppearance(light ? (int)WindowInsetsControllerAppearance.LightStatusBars : 0, (int)WindowInsetsControllerAppearance.LightStatusBars);
            win.InsetsController?.SetSystemBarsAppearance(light ? (int)WindowInsetsControllerAppearance.LightNavigationBars : 0, (int)WindowInsetsControllerAppearance.LightNavigationBars);

            //set background color. if the color is transparent, set NoLimits
            if (color == Xamarin.Forms.Color.Transparent) 
            {
                win.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.LayoutNoLimits);
            }
            else
            {
                win.ClearFlags(WindowManagerFlags.LayoutNoLimits);
            }

            win.SetStatusBarColor(color.ToAndroid());
            win.SetNavigationBarColor(color.ToAndroid());

            //none of these work
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>                 
            {
                win.DecorView.RootView.Invalidate();
                win.DecorView.RootView.RequestLayout();
                win.DecorView.RootView.ForceLayout();
                win.DecorView.RootView.RefreshDrawableState();
                win.DecorView.RefreshDrawableState();
                win.DecorView.ForceLayout();
                win.DecorView.Invalidate();
                win.DecorView.RequestLayout();
            });
        }
    }
```

The problem occurs as follows:

1. App start, first load of `HomePage`: **Correct** display of **No Limits**
2. Load `SettingsPage`: **Correct** display inside system bars limits
3. Return to `HomePage`: **Incorrect** display of page inside system bars limits
4. Turn off phone, turn on again: **Correct** display of `HomePage` with **No Limits** (it seems some sort of refresh has corrected the appearance)

I have tried all manner of methods to refresh the screen to no avail (see code above).

Any thoughts?

Comment: When you return to the HomePage did you call the method to reset the windows? And did this problem only appeared on when you get back the HomePage first time?

Comment: Hi Liyun, thanks for your reply. Once step 3 is arrived at, switching between Pages will not correct it. Only turning on and off the phone, or occasionally, switching to another app and returning fixes it. Please see my code above to see my attempts at a refresh. These are called from the HomePage.

Comment: Did you tried to test it on different device?

Comment: Actually, I've discovered a Samsung device doesn't work, but Xiaomi seems fine.